# Is there a way to turn off highlighting of pasted text in Konsole on Plasma 5.21?

Tags: plasma5, konsole

Upon upgrading to the new Plasma 5.21, one of the things I noticed is that whenever I copy and paste something into the Konsole it gets highlighted automatically. I'm curious if there's a way to turn off this feature. Is there a configuration file or setting somewhere for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a `bash` feature, not Konsole.

Use this command to turn it off:

```bsh
bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste off'
```